# Why am I not addicted to coffee?

Tags: health

> I have been drinking coffee for the last 5 years at least once a day, often twice and I have no addiction feeling yet?

**I need to be addicted to coffee and experience the feeling?**

Comment: I am not addicted, either. Just let me have  my five espresso a day and I am perfectly fine and functional member of the society. Now if you excuse me, it's  almost 9am and I need a cup.

Comment: @Mehari - Do you mean to say you do not enjoy drinking coffee? Or, do you enjoy the taste of it, but just never developed addiction/withdrawal symptoms around it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Caffeine is only mildly addictive and only shows minor physical dependence. It does not threaten physical, social or economic health the way truly addictive drugs will.
"Withdrawal" or skipping your morning cup might give you a mild headache.
Here is a link to a brief description of caffeine addiction.

http://www.m.webmd.com/a-to-z-guides/caffeine-myths-and-facts

Answer (score 4):

I also drink coffee fairly regularly and I too do not feel addiction towards it.

People's tolerances and reactions to certain chemicals, including caffeine, are always different. One person may be addicted to a substance that others are not, it simply depends on the individual.

Answer (score 0):

Coffee addiction doesn't manifest as a powerful, puke-your-guts-out kind of feeling if you don't get a fix. Rather, you just sort of feel run down and tired until you get your fix. Try withholding coffee on the weekends, then see how you feel a few weeks later on Monday as you head to work or school.